# full feature multisite blogging engine

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, blogs

is there any full feature multisite blogging engine on ruby(rails)/php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Wordpress 3.0 installation contains Multisite Support (MS)

You can [Download it here](http://wordpress.org/download/).

Here is a guide to [migrating multiple sites to Worpress 3.0 Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Multiple_Blogs_into_WordPress_3.0_Multisite).

Comment: You can also install easily on your machine or server with a ready-to-run package http://codex.wordpress.org/User:Beltranrubo/BitNami_Multisite I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the product that John Nunemaker came out with, Harmony. App built very solid on Rails and makes blog creation a snap along with any type of customization you want to add.

[Harmony App](http://get.harmonyapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In rails, mephisto is a one of good blogging engines which can be found here: http://mephistoblog.com/

And also one of good CMS is there- radiant: http://www.radiantcms.org/

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress (The [MU version](http://mu.wordpress.org/)) :)

Comment: WordPress MU is no longer a separate project; it is continuing development as part of the main WordPress branch under the name 'multi-site'